# Replacing missing values of a column vector

Tags: r, lookup, missing-data, categorical-data, data-cleaning

In a dataframe I have two categorical variables, say `qs` and `vr` of a dataframe `df`. This dataframe is quite large, but suppose that are 100 different levels in `qs`, not necessary following a pattern. The column vector `vr` - which I as said is also a categorical variable - has some missing values.

What I want to do is label the missing values that exist in `vr` according to the corresponding category or value in `qs`.

**I know *a priori*** that are 9 different categories in `qs` for which `vr` has missing values. Say, that the label for one category in `qs` is `102`and for this category in `qs` there are missing values in `vr`.

So, what I want then to do is

- if the category/label/value in qs==102 set vr==`Greece`
- if the category/label/value in qs==250 set vr==`Italy`

end so on.

Sadly, my dataframe is very complicated and I don't know how I can reproduce a simple dataframe.

Comment: The 'vr' is all NA for the 'qs' 3.  I would guess this is a simple example to show a complicated problem.  But, if the whole elements in 'vr' is NA, how do you replace it with 'c' (here it is evident that the letters follow the alphabetic pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is a 'c' in 'vr' for 'qs' value of 3, we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, vr := na.omit(vr)[1] , by = qs]
```

---

It is not clear whether the OP wanted to replace the missing values with the unique elements for 'vr' for each 'qs' or from some other values.  If it is to replace with some other values, create a key/value dataset and join with the original dataset `on` 'qs'

```
df1 <- data.table(qs = 1:4, vr = c("Serbia", "England", "Greece", "USA"))
df$qs <- as.numeric(as.character(df$qs))
setDT(df)[df1, on = "qs"][is.na(vr), vr := i.vr][, i.vr := NULL][]
```

Comment: Letters in my example are just for illustration purposes, I need to replace the missing values in `vr` with names I want. For example, if `qs==1` set "missing value to Serbia".

Comment: @msh855 I posted a comment below your question.  In your question, the 'qs' elements are all missing for 'vr' 3.  So, how would somebody know it should be replaced with 'c'?

Comment: This is not a problem, because I know with what should be replaced. So, for example, for `3` I want to set `Greece`. The real difficulty for me is that I know that are missing values in `vr` but I don't know for which categories in "qs". Finding for which category in `qs` there is a missing value in `vr` is the hardest for me, to replace it is relatively easy because I know what name to give in `vr` if I found the category in `qs`

Comment: @msh855 I think your example and your requirement is not matching.  Please update your example with what you wanted.

Comment: Can you please read again my updated post. Maybe now is much more clear.

Comment: @msh855 I read it, I think the update in my post should work for it (though not tested as you didn't show any new example)